# Como quebrar uma lista em duas listas distintas para usar no Gnuplot python?

Tags: python, plot

Um recurso do gnuplot online permite colocar seus dados em duas colunas separadas por espaço, e ele entende como os eixos "x" e "y"

http://gnuplot.respawned.com/

Estou tentando usar o gnuplot python. Presumindo que seria semelhante ao recurso online, eu coloquei "#" no que não era dado e tentei plotar. Entretanto, encontrei apenas tutorial pedindo para separar o eixo x do eixo y em duas listas distintas.

Eu tenho uma lista (que também pode ser no formato de string), como no exemplo abaixo:

`lista = ['59.99167\t-3180\r\n', '60.00000\t-3181\r\n']`

`string = 59.99167  -3180
         60.00000   -3181`

As minhas dúvidas são: como eu facilmente quebro minha lista(no caractere "\t") ou string em duas listas novas(x e y), com meus dados separados? Será que tem alguma forma de eu usar o gnuplot python sem precisar fazer isso, como ocorre no gnuplot online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não conheço o gnuplot, mas não é difícil separar sua lista em duas listas com valores `x` e `y` no Python.

O primeiro passo é quebrar os elementos a partir do '\t'. Pra isso, basta usar `split`: essa função divide uma string em uma lista de strings separadas pelo caractere ou substring passada pra ela. Podemos usar uma compreensão de lista pra aplicar a operação a todas as strings da lista em uma só linha:

```
lista = ['59.99167\t-3180\r\n', '60.00000\t-3181\r\n']
lista_split = [dado.split('\t') for dado in lista]
print(lista_split)
# [['59.99167', '-3180\r\n'], ['60.00000', '-3181\r\n']]
```

Temos agora uma lista de listas, mas não bem no formato que queremos. Pra transformar nossa lista em duas listas distintas `x` e `y`, podemos usar o [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Ele nos dá duas tuplas, então se realmente quisermos listas basta dizer:

```
x, y = zip(*lista_split)
x, y = list(x), list(y)
print(x)
# ['59.99167', '60.00000']
print(y)
# ['-3180\r\n', '-3181\r\n']
```

Como pode ver, temos agora `x` e `y` mais ou menos como queríamos, mas imagino que você queira o valor em forma de `float` ou `int`, e não como strings (inclusive com whitespace, no caso de `y`). Mais uma vez, compreensões de lista podem dar uma solução rápida:

```
x = [float(valor) for valor in x]
print(x)  # [59.99167, 60.0]
y = [float(valor) for valor in y]
print(y)  # [-3180.0, -3181.0]
```

Traduzindo:

- `x` agora é o seguinte:
- uma lista, em que:
- pra cada elemento `valor` de `x`, um dos elementos da nova lista corresponde a `float(valor)`

Comment: Funciona bem. Obrigado!!